# I can't understand how this .csv file is read

Tags: d3.js

I got this code from [this block](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051) :

```
d3.csv("data.csv", function(d, i, columns) {
    for (var i = 1, n = columns.length; i < n; ++i) d[columns[i]] = +d[columns[i]];
    return d;
    }, function(error, data) {script goes here});
```

I don't understand how the code makes the difference between strings and numbers, since the `+` in `d[columns[i]] = +d[columns[i]]` should mean everything is read as a number, no?

In the block the data looks like this :

```
State,Under 5 Years,5 to 13 Years,14 to 17 Years
CA,2704659,4499890,2159981
TX,2027307,3277946,1420518
NY,1208495,2141490,1058031
```

So at some point shouldn't the code try to interpret `CA` as a number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code iterates over the columns starting at index 1 (`for var i = 1`) which will skip the first column as the `columns` array is zero based. Since there are no more non-numerical values in the rest of the CSV everything works fine from there on.

Comment: Oh I thought it was iterating vertically along every line, thanks. But then how does the script get the name of each state? Here `x0.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.State; }));` you see that d.State is used, when it's not read from the .csv file. So even if you don't get it from d3.csv you can still use it later on?

I don't know if I'm very clear.

Comment: The first column is only skipped for conversion; the `State` property will be kept unchanged. Note, that the entire row is returned by `return d` having all its initial properties with column index 1 through n converted to numbers.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! So if I understand right, without this line `for (var i = 1, n = columns.length; i < n; ++i) d[columns[i]] = +d[columns[i]];` what would be returned would be everything as a string?